# Convert nsstring to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have the following array:

```
    NSString *testString = @"1|Car|Red|Ford";
    NSArray *testArray = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
```

Is it possible to set "1" as key and then "Car", "Red", and "Ford" as the objects for that key?

So that if I use my NSMutableDictionary in a table I can have a lot of data for each cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *testString = @"1|Car|Red|Ford";
NSArray *testArray = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
NSString *key = [testArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *values = [testArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [testArray count] - 1)];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:values forKey:key];
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua. Say I want to use that in my cell and have the cell title as "Car" and subtitle as "Red Ford" - how would I call each specific object?

Comment: You're missing some very deep basics of programming here. Try some things and then come back.